# Transform graphql to json.Python

Tags: python, json

I have an algorithm that makes a call to the `API` by `XHR` and that should return a `Json`.

Since Return is a GraphQL, it is not impossible to use JSON:

My doubts:

1-How do I get a return in `JSON` using my `graphql`.

```
Graphql: 

data = 

[{
    "operationName": "SearchQuery",
    "variables": {
      "query": buscar,
      "after": None, 
      "first": 90
    },
    "query": """
      query SearchQuery($query: String!, $first: Int!, $after: ID) {
        questionSearch(query: $query, first: $first, after: $after) {
          count
          edges {
            node {
              id
              databaseId
              author {
                id
                databaseId
                isDeleted
                nick
                avatar {
                  thumbnailUrl
                  __typename
                }
                rank {
                  name
                  __typename
                }
                __typename
              }
              content
              answers {
                nodes {
                  thanksCount
                  ratesCount
                  rating
                  __typename
                }
                hasVerified
                __typename
              }
              __typename
            }
            highlight {
              contentFragments
              __typename
            }
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
      }
    """
  }]
```

Requisition that I use mine `graphql:`

```
resp = requests.post('https://brainly.com.br/graphql/pt', json=data).json()
```

o Same always returns `JSONDecodeError`, I accept workarounds. Thanks.

Comment: the result of your request is an array of dictionaries. there is no need to convert to JSON, just index the array for the item you want.

Comment: You can of the Examples, I am not sure because when executing the same to JSONDecodeError I am afraid that with my submission I would have some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand it properly but GraphQL most common serialization format is **JSON**.

https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-JSON-Serialization

> JSON is the most common serialization format for GraphQL. Though as mentioned above, GraphQL does not require a specific serialization format.

**Try splitting the response to troubleshoot** and see if you can find what is causing the `JSONDecodeError` and whether the endpoint is a GraphlQL endpoint.

```py
resp = requests.post('https://brainly.com.br/graphql/pt', json=data)
print(resp.text())
```